# Zariski Closure in a Torus and the dimension of the quotient

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, algebraic-groups, zariski-topology

I'm reading the second chapter of Serre's *Abelian l-Adic Representations and Elliptic Curves*, and need help with the first exercise. Let $K$ be a number field and let $T$ be the Weil Restriction of the multiplicative group $\mathbb{G}_m$ over $K$, to the rationals, i.e. $T=R_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(\mathbb{G}_{m/K})$. Let $E$ be the group of units in the ring of integers of $K$, hence a subgroup of $K^*=T(\mathbb{Q})$. Denote $\bar{E}$ to be the Zariski closure of $E$ in $T$ and $T_E$ to be the torus $T/\bar{E}$. The exercise asks to show that the dimension of $T_E$ is 2 for imaginary quadratic fields and 1 for both real quadratic fields and cubic number fields with one complex place. I have just started reading about algebraic groups and am struggling with finding the Zariski closure of the unit groups in the tori. I know what the group $E$ looks like, with the help of Dirichlet's unit theorem, but am unable to proceed further. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: In the case of imaginary quadratic field, Dirichlet's unit theorem says that $E$ has rank $0$, that is $E$ is a finite cyclic group and hence it is already closed in zariski topology(finite union of closed set is closed). Then quotient of a torus by a finite group is again a torus of the same dimension.

Comment: In case of Real quadratic field, E is rank one. That is $E$ is infinite and thus $\overline{E}$ is of atleast dimension 1. I claim that $E$ is contained in kernel of the norm map $Res_{k/\mathbb{Q}}(\mathbb{G}_{m/k}) \rightarrow \mathbb{G}_{m/\mathbb{Q}}$ which is of dimension 1, since dim$Res_{k/\mathbb{Q}}(\mathbb{G}_{m/k}) = 1$. Thus $\overline{E}$ is a closed subset of a zariski close subsets of dimension 1.

Comment: One can also use rank$X(T_E)\otimes \mathbb{Q} = dim(T_E)$, where the terminology is borrowed from the book mentioned in the question.